# Global Utility Classes with PostCSS / CSS Modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, postcss, css-modules

Using [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), how can I apply a global utility class to multiple elements without duplicating the style declaration?

For example, here is a React component without CSS Modules. The relevant line is the `div` with two classes: `widget` and `clearfix`...

```
/* components/widget.jsx */

class Widget extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="widget clearfix">
        <div className="widget-alpha">Alpha</div>
        <div className="widget-beta">Beta</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`.clearfix` is a global utility class that I want to apply to many elements throughout my app:

```
/* util/clearfix.scss */

.clearfix {
  &:before, &:after { content: " "; display: table; }
  &:after { clear: both; }
}
```

I've seen various ways of importing `.clearfix` into a CSS Module, but in each case the style declarations are redefined for each occurrence where the class is applied. Here's one example:

```
/* widget.scss */

.widget {
  // other styles
  composes: clearfix from '../util/clearfix.scss';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through trial and error, I found that you can declare `:global` in the selector where the utility class is employed (not where it's defined):

```
.widget {

  // other styles

  :global {
    composes: clearfix;
  }
}
```

To avoid messy and repetitive `import` and `from` statements, I used an `index.scss` file to import the utility files and then import that in any partial where a utility class is needed.